# MQ Messaging between two applications not happening for large data messaging

Tags: ibm-mq

I am using IBM MQ Manager to send and receive messages between two applications.

However I noticed that when the size of the response message is 10623134 the response file is sent. But when the size is 17123460, the response file is not sent. The maximum message lenght in the MQ config for the response queue is set to 4194304.

Please what could be the cause of this when the message is not sent ?

Answer (score 0):

I take it you are new to MQ.  Please read the manual.  4MB (4194304) is the default maximum message length that can be put to any queue.

1. If you want to put a bigger message to the queue then you need to
   increase the queue's the maximum message length attribute.
2. If the message is going from a client application (connecting in client mode) to a queue manager you need to increase the channel's the maximum message length attribute plus you need to do (1).
3. If the message is going between 2 queue managers then there are several things that need to be updated:

   - point (1) from above
   - increase the queue manager's the maximum message length attribute
   - increase the dead letter queue's the maximum message length attribute
   - increase the sender channel's the maximum message length attribute
   - increase the transmit queue's the maximum message length attribute

> Please what could be the cause of this when the message is not sent ?

What was the MQ Reason Code that MQ returned to the application?  That should ALWAYS be the first place you start.